# passport object empty not getting called in passport/express app, not calling deserializeUser

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

I have an angularjs app on a different domain calling requests to an express based api.  For example, I have an app running on localhost:9000 and connecting to an api @ localhost:3000.  Express is 3.51, passport: 0.1.18, Angularjs: 1.2

For express I've set cors and set the allow credentials to true:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});
```

I am initializing passport before the router:

```
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());*
app.use(app.router);
```

And in my AnguarJS front-end I do set the defaults to use credentials on my http requests:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Am I missing anything? Upon login I do see serializeUser getting called. On subsequent requests, I see the cookie being sent in the headers:

```
GET /api/shows?themes=true HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:9000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.122 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:9000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __distillery=OHFOIWEFOWEIJFO2352039832904BLAH; connect.sid=s%lweifjeill32ij3ri3KSLIJSEF.selfijseilfjsefeljkfe%2B%2BqUeXF0k
If-None-Match: "-2134790151"
```

However deserializeUser never gets called because the passport object is empty on req.session. Am I missing anything? I also have a login page on the same domain (localhost:3000) and the login/passport is working fine. So I think it has to do something with the cross domain or header settings, but I don't know how else to debug this.

**Update - If I move all my front end code into the api application (so that there is no cross domain happening, the authentication and session is working fine...**

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all the settings were correct, but on the initial login, I was sending a post request with the username/password and `{withCredentials: false}`. This creates a new session but the cookie is referencing onto the existing session. Once I commented this out, I was able to ge it working.